# context-root for sub context

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, websphere

I have multiple war files in my ear. Each war file corresponds to a particular version. This is packaged structure:

```
TestServiceEAR
          ServiceOneWAR  -->  http://host:port/test/1.0
          ServiceTwoWAR  -->  http://host:port//test/2.0.
```

I want to target ServiceOneWAR as http://host:port/test/1.0 and ServiceTwoWAR as http://host:port/test/2.0. I tried to set the context-roots in TestServiceEAR/EARContent/META-INF/application.xml as /test/1.0 and /test/2.0, but that does not work.

Please suggest if this can be achieved in Websphere application server. I do not have access to a web server in my organization.

The application.xml is:

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <application xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/application_6.xsd" version="6">
      <display-name>TestServiceEAR</display-name>
      <module>
        <web>
          <web-uri>TestService_v1.war</web-uri>
          <context-root>/test/1.0</context-root>
        </web>
      </module>
      <module id="Module_1431504891524">
        <web>
          <web-uri>TestService_v2.war</web-uri>
          <context-root>/test/2.0</context-root>
        </web>
      </module>
      <library-directory>lib</library-directory>
    </application>
```

Got this resolved. The issue was that I was updating the context in application.xml and it was reset to the previous value in pom.xml. After updating pom.xml the issue was resolved.

```
<webModule>
    <groupId>${war.groupId}</groupId>
    <artifactId>${war.artifactId}</artifactId>
    <uri>${war.artifactId}.war</uri>
    <bundleFileName>${war.artifactId}.war</bundleFileName>
    <contextRoot>/test/1.0</contextRoot>
</webModule>
```

Comment: can you post your entire application.xml file?

Comment: What is not working for you? I've just tested it and jsp  pages are properly served from test/1.0 and test/2.0 contexts.

Comment: Thanks Gas and Thilak for taking time to look into this.